# Make a code "forwarding referencable"

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

I opened [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842291/c-confusion-about-forwarding-reference) post about forwarding reference, this is a (hopefully) MCVE code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct MultiMemoizator {
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
    ReturnType callFunction(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> memFunc, Args&&... args) {

    }
};

typedef vector<double> vecD;

vecD sort_vec (const vecD& vec) {
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
    vecD vec;
    std::function<vecD(const vecD&)> sortFunc(sort_vec);
    MultiMemoizator mem;
    mem.callFunction<vecD, vecD>(sortFunc, vec);
}
```

Since this is not the whole code, maybe I'll have to add extra code based on the answers.

Anyway, as was suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36842684/4480180) answer, forwarding reference is not possible with this version, since `Args` is not deduced.

So my question is: is it possible to make this code "forwarding referencable"?

Comment: What about the linked answer is insufficient? When you're explicitly providing the template arguments, the overload isn't viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to perfect-forward your arguments, you need to have the types deduced. You can do this by deducing the arguments to the function and the parameters to the functor separately:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... FunArgs, typename... Args>
ReturnType callFunction(std::function<ReturnType(FunArgs...)> memFunc,
                        Args&&... args) 
{
    //...
}
```

Then you can call `callFunction` without template parameters and have everything deduced:

```
mem.callFunction(sortFunc, vec);
```

Comment: I have added a bit of information from the standard on [the cited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842291/c-confusion-about-forwarding-reference/36842684#36842684) to explain why template argument deduction fails in the case where you have `Args...` inside the `function`, maybe it's worth  expanding a bit on your answer ;)

Comment: Am I wrong, or this solution is type unsafe? I cannot edit the answer now, but as you can imagine you're gonna call memFunc(args), and so you're gonna find at runtime if this legal or not

Comment: @Holt I'm on my phone now, so feel free to edit this answer or add one of your own :).

Comment: @justHelloWorld why would this be done at runtime? All the types are checked at compile time.

Comment: @TartanLlama do you think that after Holt considerations you code could still work?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Yes. I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @justHelloWorld I did not update my answer because when writing it I got to the fact that the problem is not really into the forwarding of your args, but rather in the way you are storing `sort_vect` into `sortFunc`: You transform a function taking `A const&` or `A&&` into one taking `A` so you are going to make a lot of copy without realizing it. You are trying to make `callFunction` forwarding your `args...` but your code is already broken because of the way you stored your functions.

Comment: @Holt Where does that transformation take place? If you pass in a `std::function<int(int const&)>` then `FunArgs` will be deduced as `int const&`, not `int`.

Comment: @TartanLlama Just here: `std::function<vecD(vecD)> sortFunc(sort_vec);`. There is nothing wrong with your code, I think the problem here is in the design of the original code, not what you propose.

Comment: @Holt Oh, sure. If you made that `std::function<vecD(const vecD&)> sortFunc(sort_vec)` then it would be fine though.

Comment: @TartanLlama Yes of course. I was simply trying to explain to the OP that before it tries to make `callFunction` forwarding argument correctly, it should probably rethink part of its design (from the original code in the linked question) or its perfect forwarding would not make sense.

Comment: @Holt Oh gosh you're right! I'll edit the answer so it will be clearer if someone will read it in future. But anyway, TartanLlama solution is correct at the end, right? The only problem is that it doesn't warn you in case of these kind of errors, while your solution using `decltype` does. The problem is that looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045579/variadic-template-pack-within-decltype) question for example you can use `decltype` only with expressions, not with packs...so there is no way to apply your solution with variadic templates...

Comment: ps: original question updated with `const vecD&` in both `sort_vec` and `sortFunc`

Comment: @justHelloWorld Unfortunately, the method with `decltype` is too rigid I think: You cannot pass an lvalue `A` to a method waiting a `const A&` because the deduced type will be `A&` and not `const A&`. Or you cannot pass a `A&&` to a method accepting a `A const&` while this may be perfectly valid in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I will add a bit of details regarding @TartanLlama answer on **why** your code fails to compile (even without the explicit template parameters) but also why (in my own opinion) your code is *dangerous*.

In the following, I will use only a simple type `T` instead of your parameter pack `Args...` because it is simpler to explain and does not change the meaning.

### A bit of reminder on forwarding references...

First, let's take a simpler example than yours with simply the following:

```
template <typename T>
void f (T&&);
```

Now, let's instanciate `f` from various sources, let's assume with have the following variables:

```
std::string s;
const std::string cs;
```

...then:

```
f(s); // instanciate f<std::string&>
f(cs); // instanciate f<const std::string&>
f(std::string()); // instanciate f<std::string&&>
```

You should be wondering: *Why is the first instanciation `f<std::string&>` instead of `f<std::string>`?*, but the standard tells you (§14.8.2.1#3 **[temp.deduct.call]**):

> If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an
>   lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

### Back to our initial snippet!

Now, let's complicate a bit our example:

```
template <typename T> 
struct A {};

template <typename T>
void f (A<T>, T&&);
```

And one instantiation:

```
std::string s;
A<std::string> as;
f(as, s);
```

The above is equivalent to your example, and will fails to compile, but why... ? Well, as explained above, when you have an *lvalue*, the deduced type for `T&&` is `T&`, not `T`, and thus the type deduction fails for `A<T>` because the compiler is expecting `A<std::string&>` and you are giving a `A<std::string>`.

So now we know that we have to do the following:

```
A<std::string&> ars;
A<std::string const&> acrs;
f(ars, s); // good
f(acrs, cs); // good
```

### Why is it dangerous?

Ok so now, this should be good:

```
A<std::string&&> arrs;
f(arrs, std::string());
```

But it is not... Because when `T` is deduced as a rvalue reference, `T` is simply `T`, so the compiler is expecting `A<std::string>`.

So here is the problem: You are going to give a *rvalue* to a method that is going to forward it to a function expecting an *lvalue*. That's not wrong, but it is probably not what you'd have expected.

### How to deal with it?

The first possibility is to force the type of the first parameter regardless of the deduced type for `T`, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
void f (A<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>, T&&);
```

But note:

1. You would have to add more stuff to deal with `const`.
2. One may wonder the usefulness of `T&&` when the type of the first argument is fixed (in your case, at least).

The second possibility (**warning: I don't know if this is standard!**) is to move the first parameter at the end and then deduce the type from `t`:

```
template <typename T>
void f (T &&t, A<decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>);
```

Now you have an exact match between the deduced type for `T` and the expected type for `A`.

Unfortunately I don't know how to make the above work with variadic templates...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have still some doubts:

1. `f(s); // instanciate f<std::string&>` it's because of the infamous collapsing rule, where `A& && becomes A&`, right?
2. In your solution I didn't get `A<decltype(std::forward<T>(t))>`
3. What do you mean by "warning: I don't know if this is standard!" and what could be the problem with that?
4. Your esample is not a little bit different, since we are using `template<typename T1, typename T2>` according to @TartanLlama 's solution?

Comment: @justHelloWorld 1. Not really, it's because of the quoted standard part: If you have a templated function waiting for a forwarding reference `T&&` and you are giving it an lvalue (`s` in this case), then the deduced argument template will be `T&` and not `T` (even for the other parameters!). This is a different behaviour than if you pass an rvalue in which case the deduced parameter is still `T` for the other arguments.

Comment: @justHelloWorld 2. Instead of using `T` for the template argument, you can used the deduce type for `t` which can be retrieved using `decltype` and `std::forward` (will be `T&` if the given parameter is an lvalue and `T&&` if it's an rvalue). 3. I simply mean that I don't know if you can use an parameter name in the definitiion of a following parameter. 4. I was extending on your code (why it does not work, and why it may behave strangly), not on the proposed code by Tartan.

Comment: By your answer for point 4. seems like @TartanLlama code could be a working solution, or am I wrong?

Comment: @justHelloWorld Tartan code will basically work the same as the code with `std::remove_reference`, but it is not what you want I think, I will add a bit at the end of my answer to explain why.

Comment: @Holt My code isn't the same as the `std::remove_reference` version: it deduces the parameters for the `std::function` you pass in, which is exactly what you want for perfect forwarding into it.

Comment: @TartanLlama Sorry, I mean why it has the same problem as my code with `std::remove_reference`. I am editing the answer to explain why these code are "dangerous".